# AJAX request not sending to URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to send an ajax request to a URL, expecting to get a json response, however, the request doesn't seem to be sending to /login. Instead, it remains on the current url and add the formData params to it. It is also not sensing "POST". What's wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login").click(function() {
    var formData = {username: username, password: password}
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/login",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
        var json_x = data;
        alert(json_x['data']);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

html:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username">Username</input>
  <input type="password" name="password">Password</input>
  <button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: An ajax call isn't supposed to change your current URL. It's just a call to the server, expecting a response in the background.

Comment: is button with id #login of type submit or button?

Comment: If you need to redirect to different page you should use  window.location.href

Comment: If it is submit button then please check your console error. There might be some error. may be your ajax is not working and form is simply getting posted via get method

Comment: there is no console error.

Comment: @Maverick is on the right track. You should probably change it to type button instead and try that out.

Comment: Can you please paste form html over here?

Comment: The button doesn't work now that I've changed to typed button.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login").click(function() {
    // you forgot to get value of username and password
    var formData = {username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val()};
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/login",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
}); 

<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">Username</input>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">Password</input>
  <button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: bad accessibility design changing to type=button, user can't use keyboard to submit. Better to just bind to form submit event and prevent the default

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE3:
See the new declaration of formData.

```
var formData = {
    username: $("input[name='username']").val(),
    password: $("input[name='password']").val()
};
```

Comment: You're formdata is not being declared properly. I'm going to write up a new answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

`alert(json_x.data);`

instead of

`alert(json_x['data']);`

also change this line

`var formData = {username: username, password: password}`

into

`var formData = $(this).parent().serialize();`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use $("button") instead of $("#login").

I've solved it.

Comment: I'm sure that's not the only reason why it's working. It should be able to grab the element by its Id if you put in the correct Id. And if you plan on adding another button to the page, that would be a bad idea.